# Clicking the description text of a question should lead to that question

Tags: feature-request

Every once in a while I'm using my tablet to surf on the SOFU network. And every time I do so, I try to click on the description text of the question.

E.g. Clicking inside the green area should lead you to the question:

[image]

This proposal is something I see coming on many sites for better mobile access. For example the german [H-Online](http://heise.de). Also I don't see it being distractive for the Desktop-users, as the style of the text should remain the same, and therefore not appear as a link to them.

Comment: I'm not sure this would be horrible for desktop users, either. It would definitely give us a bigger target. Perhaps some kind of hover effect to make it more obvious what is happening?

Comment: As you can't hover on a touchscreen, there should be no difference in appearance, because on a Desktop the cursor will become different anyway when hovering over a link.

Comment: @twall many tablets tap-hold hover. Or something.

Comment: Do they? I have an Android Froyo tablet, that is only capable of "clicking". Holding will lead to special functions of the browser app in use. The same goes for the XOOM (Honeycomb tablet) and the iPad (iOS). I've never seen something like a hover function.

Comment: That would make touching the tag below it more difficult; I like some whitespace to avoid accidentally touching the wrong thing. But true, in overviews without summaries/descriptions, the tags are right below the title, so not a lot of whitespace there either. And I assume that the green area in your mock up can be a bit less tall to leave some whitespace.